# Which country spends the most on board & card games?

Tags: statistics

I've been wondering which country spends the most money on board / card games? Are there any statistics available?

Comment: The one with the greatest number of MtG players :-)

Comment: What about other collecting card games (Pokemon, Yugio or however you write it, Harry Potter, ...) and other board games? Is it one game to dominate them all, to find the money, one game to bring it all to Wizards of the Coast and bind it?

Comment: To determine this, you would need to know the sales information for every manufacturer of board games and card games, broken down by Country. Magic the Gathering, even with it's life span and overall success, would only be a limited indicator.

Comment: @DrunkCynic not necessarily - I can get a good estimator of (say) the country that spends the most on wine simply by asking consumers how much they spend on wine; I don't need to talk to every wine retailer. No reason I can't (in theory) do the same for board games.

Comment: @PhilipKendall - That could develop an approximation of the countries spending, if you polled a sufficient portion of the populace of each nation to generate a strong per capita correlation. In order to know which country spends the most, the hard sales numbers and approximate exchange values would provide discrete differences.

Comment: @moose Total or per capita?

Comment: @John I don't care. If I have one, I can calculate the other easily. But I think  per capita would be the more interesting one.

Comment: you might have better luck on http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think [GfK](http://www.gfk.com/) should have these numbers readily available, but they don't come for free.

Answer (score 4):

So looking online I found [this](https://www.wired.com/2009/03/mf-settlers/?currentPage=all) from 2015.

It says

> More are sold per capita in Germany than anywhere else on earth

Magic the Gathering is big, with something like 20 million players worldwide, however that will pale in comparison to board game sales so I'd be likely to ignore card games as they won't add a huge amount overall compared to board games.

So in conclusion, Germany looks like the best bet

Comment: That would also track with Essen Spieltage, which is I believe the biggest board gaming convention there is world wide, held in Essen, Germany. Spieltage means game days in english.